# Ошибка "Undefined offset:

Tags: php

вот такая ошибка у меня `ErrorException in SteamAuth.php line 206:
Undefined offset: 1`
Тут весь код ошибок:
http://prntscr.com/lb2cmo
А вот то, что на 206 строке `$this->steamId = is_numeric($matches[1]) ? $matches[1] : 0;`
   Весь код:http://prntscr.com/lb2d0k . Вот и вопрос, как это исправить?

Comment: А если вывести содержимое `$matches`.. ?

Comment: Сделайте проверку на наличие

Answer (score 0):

У вас нет данных в $matches

```
$t = ( isset($matches) && is_numeric($matches[1]) ) ? $matches[1] : 0;
echo $t;
```

в вашей ситуации

```
$this->steamId = ( isset($matches) && is_numeric($matches[1]) ) ? $matches[1] : 0;
```